# Django search_fields adding DUPLICATE left outer join to django query if it have .annotate

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Django search_fields adding DUPLICATE left outer join with appliance table to Django query as it have .annotate(appliances_count=Count('appliances'))

#### View

```
class AppliancePoolViewSet(VneCommonViewSet):
    serializer_class = vne_serializers.AppliancePoolSerializer
    search_fields = ('pk', 'name', 'notes', 'appliances__name')

    # filter appliance pools by customer
    def get_queryset(self):
        customer = getattr(self.request.user, 'customer', None)
        if not customer:
            return models.AppliancePool.objects.none()
        return models.AppliancePool.objects.filter(
            customer=1).prefetch_related('appliances'
            ).annotate(appliance_count=Count('appliances'))
```

First it is adding join for annotate, and later search_field is also adding the same join again as it have field 'appliances__name', which is causing incorrect data for appliance_count.

How can I restrict addition of duplicate join which is done by Django filters using search_fields attribute?

Answer (score 3):

There are some note when using Django ORM:

1. First, the table join will be duplicated by:
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

I also found that it will affect when we using same `relation` in different place like: filter, annotate
Django will consider all those are single and should not merge

2. After deeper look on Django code, I found this:
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects

This will help to avoid spanning relations, we will have only 1 table join.

Sorry that my post will **NOT** help on the case: `prefetch_related`
Hope this will help other, as I found this one when search the solution for https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18437

Answer (score -1):

I found an work around for this.
I replaced annotate with .extra('Query to get appliance count').
I did not used join in query inside extra. So final query have only single join, no duplicate join.

Comment: `extra` will cause wrong Group By, it is also hard to use on filter